# How to insert new key and value based on user input, at index path?

Tags: objective-c

i have an nsmutablearray called orderarray that holds json, and in each dictionary there is the following:

```
{"code":"4783","product":"milk"}
```

Now based on a user's textfield input i want to add a new key in that dictionary at the index path with a key of "toorder" and a value of "toorder.text"

Here is my current code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableObject=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[orderarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[mutableObject setObject:@"toorder.text" forKey:@"toorder"];
[orderarray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:mutableObject];
```

and i get the error:

> [__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

---

In my h. file i have

NSMutableArray* orderarray;

And then in my m. file:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"urlhere"]];

        NSError* error;

        orderarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                            options:kNilOptions
                                                              error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (!error) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `orderarray` is immutable. You have to provide the option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to get mutable objects:

```
orderarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                               error:&error];
```

Comment: Thx but how do i do that?

Comment: Please show the code where you populate `orderarray`.